# Combining Labled with LabelStyle

Tags: plotting, style, labeled

I try to add a Style to my Labled plot. However, when I combine Labled with Label Style, I do not succeed.

```
Plot[Labeled[x, "G", .3, LabelStyle -> Bold], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Gives me

[image: Helpless try]

As I need to combine different curves I have to use `Labled`.

Is there a common solution to this problem?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica? It works in 12.0.

Comment: I am using 11.0. Thanks a lot though! I was getting crazy because the documentation suggested `LabelStlye`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command works in Mathematica 12.0.

If it does not work in an older version, you can try

```
Plot[Labeled[x, Style["G", Bold], .3], {x, 0, 1}]
```